# Issue with code "changing the elements class"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having an issue with my code as I want to make it so my elements change according to button presses

```js
var segSelectedy = "a";
var segSelectedx = 1;

function keydown(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    //left
    if (document.getElementById(segSelectedy + "" + (segSelectedx - 1)) != null) {
      document.getElementById("Element" + segSelectedy + "" + segSelectedx).className == "unselected";
      segSelectedx = segSelectedx - 1;
      document.getElementById("Element" + segSelectedy + "" + segSelectedx).className == "selected";
    }
  } else if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    //right
    if (document.getElementById(segSelectedy + "" + (segSelectedx + 1)) != null) {
      document.getElementById("Element" + segSelectedy + "" + segSelectedx).className == "unselected";
      segSelectedx = segSelectedx + 1;
      document.getElementById("Element" + segSelectedy + "" + segSelectedx).className == "selected";
    }
  }
}

document.onkeydown = keydown;
```

```html
<body>
  <table class="console">
    <tr>
      <th id="a1"><button id="Elementa1" class="selected">Steam Games</button></th>
      <th id="a2"><button id="Elementa2" class="unselected">Settings</button></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Application: https://coffee-console.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: Have you tried `.classList.toggle` instead of trying to assigning className with `==` like shown here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_toggle_class

Comment: I saw the `.classList.toggle` and considered it and then realized the application of said attribute wouldn't be appropriate @vahdet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//                                                                              *
//                                                                              *
document.getElementById("Element" + segSelectedy + "" + segSelectedx).className = "unselected";
```

just **one** `=` otherwise its not an assignment.

This applies to every line like the above.